# Sharing screenshots in share sheets

Tags: swift, sharing

I am making an aracade-style game and when the player loses I give them the option to share their score via the iOS share sheet. What I want to know is, how can I have them share a screenshot taken right when they die along with some text. I already know how to make it so that they share text but I want the screenshot as well. I set it up like this so that the game takes a screenshot right when the player dies:

```
func screenShotMethod() {
    //Create the UIImage
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view!.frame.size)
    view!.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    //Save it to the camera roll
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)

    println("screenshot")
}
```

Then I run this function at the GameOver Sequence like this:

```
    if gameOver == 0{

gameOver = 1

***screenShotMethod()***

movingObjects.speed = 0

movingObjects.removeFromParent()

backgroundMusicPlayer.stop()
```

Now what I want to be able to do is access this screenshot so that it can be used in the sharing option, but deleted as soon as the player hits replay if the player doesn't share that score. Right now I have sharing set up like this:

```
if shareButton.containsPoint(location){

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view!.frame.size)
        view!.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        //Save it to the camera roll
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)

        println("screenshot")

        var postImage = UIImage(named: "\(image)")

        socialShare(sharingText: "I just got \(score) points in Deez Nuts! Bet you can't beat that! #DeezNuts", sharingImage: UIImage(named: "\(postImage)"), sharingURL: NSURL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/app/"))


    }
```

Please be specific and straightforward because I am new to developing apps. Also I am using Swift if you didn't already notice. Thank you very much.

Comment: socialShare not found, help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to delete this line

```
var postImage = UIImage(named: "\(image)")
```

Because image is already an UIImage so just use sharingImage: image

```
socialShare(sharingText: "I just got \(score) points in Deez Nuts! Bet you can't beat that! #DeezNuts", sharingImage: image , sharingURL: NSURL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/app/")!)
```

Comment: socialShare not found, help!